# PHP Doc generic type declaration

Tags: php, phpdoc

I'm working on a library which uses the phpDocumentor specification on determining the type system using reflection. However, I couldn't find any information about generic type declarations.

Is there any way a generic type declaration should be specified?

For example: is there any specification (in-progress) which specifies anything like:

```
/**
 * @template <T extends Base>
 */
class Collection {

    /**
     * @return Iterator<T>
     */
    function get_iterator();

}
```

**Note** that the code above is just an example to illustrate what I mean by *generic type declarations*. I do not want this achieve anything to do with collections and iterators.

Comment: PHP does not have generics? where are you getting this?

Comment: Doesn't this look a bit like you want `abstract class Collection implements \Iterator {}`?

Comment: No, I would like to know if there is a valid way to specify a generic type for a library I'm working on. The code is just an example.

Comment: @NDM Java also doesn't have all generic type information at runtime. So the same could be achieved with PHP.

Comment: No, this is not possible in PHP. There is no notion of generics, and thus there is nu way to annotate it in the DocBlocks.

Comment: @NDM I understand that it isn't supported in PHP. That doesn't mean it couldn't be supported in phpDocumentor or any derivation. That is what my question is about.

Comment: then the question is not clear at all, please use a concrete example, the current one does not make clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: @NDM Because you don't understand the question, doesn't mean it isn't clear.

Comment: This is likely the next gen php doc, if it gets approved: https://github.com/phpDocumentor/fig-standards/blob/master/proposed/phpdoc.md

Comment: @goat Thanks. However it seems like only `@return` will support generics, I can't find a specification for defining generic classes.

Comment: Generics in the PSR-5 draft are limited to arraylike objects. There is a [proper generics proposal](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/genericshttps://wiki.php.net/rfc/generics) for PHP.

Answer (score 6):

There apparently was some interest in the related topic of object specialization because that was [added to PSR-5](https://github.com/phpDocumentor/fig-standards/blob/master/proposed/phpdoc.md#abnf):

> generic          = collection-type "<" [type-expression "," *SP] type-expression ">"

**Edit:** and [then removed](https://github.com/phpDocumentor/fig-standards/commit/eb07c50881248dc7219de3f1ff3080362b6e8477#diff-9a10a11696dc38209c125ea9c57a565f) as Jack notes below, albeit with a stated expectation that they'll return in one form or another before it's standardised

However, it doesn't provide a means to define a class as generic, and PSR-5 has been abandoned for a long while. The de-facto standard, phpDocumentor, [does not in any way define support for such syntax](http://docs.phpdoc.org/references/phpdoc/types.html#abnf).

If you want to informally mark up generics, you're best off making up your own syntax (inspired by similar syntax that already exists like [Closure's documentation](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Generic-Types) or [JSDoc](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-typedef.html)) while carefully avoiding anything that could actively confuse phpDocumentor, something like:

```
/**
 * @template {Base} T
 */
/**
 * @return Iterator {Iterator<T>}
 */
```

If you want to do it formally, you'll need to switch to another documentation system like [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/).

Comment: [It looks like generics have been removed from the PSR for the time being.](https://github.com/phpDocumentor/fig-standards/commit/eb07c50881248dc7219de3f1ff3080362b6e8477#diff-9a10a11696dc38209c125ea9c57a565f)

Comment: @JackWilsdon thanks, I've updated the answer to note this

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check out the psalm project.

https://psalm.dev/docs/

https://github.com/vimeo/psalm

It supports generics in the documentation, as well as so much more. It's also used by Symfony's DB ORM, doctrine.

It supports Emacs, Phpstorm/Intellij, vim, and visual studio

Answer (score 0):

Psalm supports this via

```php
/**
 * @template T of Foo
 */
```

Ref: https://medium.com/vimeo-engineering-blog/uncovering-php-bugs-with-template-a4ca46eb9aeb